# Help completing proofs regarding limits

Tags: analysis, limits

1) Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(n-1)/(n+1)=1.$
Solution:
We want to prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for which:
$$n>N \implies |f(n)-1|< \epsilon$$
Here's what I've tried:

$$|(n-1)/(n+1) - 1| = |-2/(n+1)| = 2/|n+1|.$$ 
This is where I got stuck.

2) Show that the function $f$ is bounded when $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ exists,
using the same definition as above and using reverse triangle inequality
$|f(x)-A| < e$. using reverse triangle inequality
$||f(x)|-|A|| \leq |f(x)-A| < e$

$$||f(x)|-|A|| < e.$$

Should I now check when $|f(x)|-|A| \geq 0$ and when |$f(x)| - |A|<0$ to get rid of the absolute value sign?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{n-1}{n+1}=1-\frac{2}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Put f(n) = (n -1)/(n+1) .For your E > 0 ==> you need : 2/(n+1) < E ==> n + 1 > 2/E ==> n > 2/E - 1. You just need to pick w = [2/E - 1] + 10 ( the greatest integer function less than or equal to 2/E - 1), then if n > w ==> / f(n) - 1 / < E.

2) For this case you need some extra condition to ensure boundedness of your function. For example take f(x) = 1/x if x > 0, and 0 when x = 0. This function f has limit f = 0 as x --> + infinity but it is not bounded. The condition could be that f be continuous on R+. So if f is continuous on R+ then we can show f is bounded. So let e  = 1 be given and assume lim f = L > 0, then there is an M > 0 such that / f(x) - L / < 1 whenever x > M. This means L - 1 < f(x) < L + 1. So / f(x) / <= L + 2. On [0, M] f is continuous hence bounded , so there is an N such that /f(x)/ <= N on [0,M] . Thus choose K = max{N, L + 2} then /f(x)/ <= K for all non-negative real x's ==> f is bounded.